# Kid struggling with Lichess 7

Tags: lichess

My kid is able to play Lichess 6 and win most time. I'm looking for ways to help him win with Lichess 7. He tries and fails and Is getting disillusioned. I'm wondering if there is too much jump between 6 and 7. Not much of a chess player myself to help him out.

FYI: He is being coached.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but I can't help but think that many coaches and trainers advise players seeking to improve to play real humans and not bots for a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, results against bots aren't a great indicator of chess strength. A chess bot is an opponent that can play almost perfectly but will make mistakes at random to let you win, so this is not a great model for how "real" chess works. Too many factors like luck, style, time/focus and so on can have an impact on the result.

Either way, the best strategy to beat stronger bots is improving your overall chess skill. This means keeping to work on tactics, calculation, strategy, openings and endgames. But still, for a better assessment of how fast progress is happening, results against real humans are a much better reference.

I'm not sure about the levels of the different Stockfish bots on Lichess, but level 8 is basically unbeatable even for top level humans.